# tympanus multi-level-menu - how to remember opened panel on page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've started using this plugin for multilevel side menu:
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/11/17/multi-level-menu/

When i grabbed example code from this page i saw that plugin don't it my needs.
I mean, when i will reload page, everytime main panel is opened, and i'm looking for any solution, to keep track about last opened panel.
I can use localstorge or cookies, but i don't see any way how to select opened, store this info and then call function to open this saved panel.
I don't provide example code, as i'm using this code from link.

Thank you for any ideas !

Answer (score 0):

In the tympanus code when you select an item in the menu, the `current` class is added to the selected item (for `menuItem` and `menuLevel`). It means that you can get the current selected `menuItem` and `menuLevel` by matching this class and then save it in a cookie.

```
function getCurrentMenuItemSelected() {
  var currentMenuItem = $(".menu__item .menu__link--current");
  console.log(currentMenuItem.html());
}

function getCurrentMenuLeveItemSelected() {
  var currentMenuLevel = $(".menu__level.menu__level--current");
  console.log(currentMenuLevel.data("menu"));
}

getCurrentMenuItemSelected();
getCurrentMenuLeveItemSelected();
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for reply. Your idea is cool but now im not suer if plugin allows (has function) to open saved panel. And even if i will be able to open this panel after page reload, i'm wondering if bredcrumbs etc. will work...

Comment: I think for a simple example like this it ll be faster to do it by yourself. Save some states in cookies and add a specific class on page load is not hard.

Comment: Thank you. I've added this code for tests and this selects desired panel - in this case (2) but menu is loosing synvhro now - no breadcrumbs and back button to previous panel, so looks relly bad.$(".menu__level").removeClass('menu__level--current');
        $(".menu__level").eq(2).addClass('menu__level--current');